# Is there a way to trigger Finder's "quick look" window with Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, quicklook

I am using Applescript to automate some tasks in the OSX Finder. The script opens up a folder and selects the first image in that folder. I would like it to also bring up the "quick look" window (exactly as if the user had pressed the space bar).

I did find a way to fire up quick look from the command line using [qlmanage](http://osxdaily.com/2007/12/24/use-quick-look-from-the-command-line/), but that brings up a static quick look window, which is no longer tied to the finder selection.

Code so far:

```
property folderPath : "/Volumes/Media/Images"

on run {}
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
            set imageFolder to folder (folderPath as POSIX file)
            set imageFile to first item of imageFolder
            select imageFile
            -- show quick look?
    end tell
end run
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Updated*** (with thanks to [Kevin Ballard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/582/kevin-ballard)):

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "y" using command down
```

Note: this requires that "enable access for assistive devices" is selected in the "Universal Access" control panel.

Comment: It might be better to do something like `keystroke "Y" using command down` instead.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard: What does that do?

Comment: It presses ⌘Y, which is the keyboard shortcut corresponding with the File->Quick Look menuitem. Of course, it might be even better to use Universal Access to invoke that menuitem directly instead of trying to type the shortcut.

Comment: That's perfect. The "y" had to be lower case for it to work, but it works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to do it by scripting the Finder you can run the following shell command

```
qlmanage -p thefile
```

In an Applescript you might do this like

```
do shell script "qlmanage -p " & "thepath/thefile"
```

Depending upon what you are doing this might be much easier.  Especially if you primarily just have a set of paths.

If you have an existing Applescript path you can send it like this

```
set p to POSIX path of  mypath
do shell script "qlmanage -pr " & quoted form of p
```

Comment: I tried qlmanage but it does not work as desired (see the second paragraph in my question)

Comment: Doh.  Missed that somehow.  Then using GUI scripting is the way to go.